# Can I prove two numbers are different using a computer?

Tags: proof-writing, numerical-methods

I have two functions $f, g : \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$. I want to prove $f(0) \neq g(0)$. Both $f$ and $g$ are made up of functions available in a standard scientific computing package like scipy in python. If I evaluate $f(0)$ and $g(0)$ and the two differ, does this count as a proof that $f(0) \neq g(0)$?

I'm guessing that it comes down to the numerical error in those functions. But also maybe there's a bug that I don't know about. What would it take for this to count as a proof? Would I need provable bounds on $f(0)$ and $g(0)$ and then I can use the numerical estimate to show they must be different?

As a simpler example, if I want to show $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \neq 0.4$, can I just use the fact that `1 / sqrt(2 * pi) - 0.4` is not within rounding of zero?

Comment: https://0.30000000000000004.com/

Comment: @JMoravitz but what if they differ in the first couple significant digits? Does that change things? What if they differ by orders of magnitude? Is there a point where I can be confident that I've proven the two numbers distinct?

Comment: $((0.1+0.2) - 0.3)\times 10^n$

Comment: @JMoravitz ok thank you for the example. In that case though I can see that the difference is small and it would make me suspicious that it's just numerical imprecision. But what if my computer says $|f(0) - g(0)| \approx 10$ or something? Does that count?

Comment: "*but in that case the difference is small...*"  $((0.1+0.2)-0.3)\times 10^n$ for large $n$ will be *large*, as large as you want, according to several computer programming languages... when we know in reality by pen and paper methods the answer should simply be zero.  There is no lower bound with regards to what order of magnitude the difference between two numbers who ought to be equal according to pen and paper happen to be if asking a computer to evaluate it in two different ways.

Comment: The punchline is that you should avoid floating point arithmetic on a computer if precision is important, and use floating point arithmetic on computers only for estimations.  Convert floating point problems into integer problems (*for example, storing monetary amounts in quantities of cents, not dollars*).  If you want to prove two non-integers equal, then doing it by hand is safer.  For example, knowing that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ is irrational and so could not possibly equal $0.4$

Comment: @alfalfa See also the long and entertaining [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) next door on SO.

Comment: @JMoravitz ahh thank you, I hadn't appreciated that. Would you be up for turning that into an answer?

Comment: @dxiv thank you! I will peruse

Comment: Note that all those comments about the peculiarities of finite precision of floating point arithmetic are irrelevant. If you have enough memory and the language is powerful enough (Python is Turing complete) you can compute anything that can be computed. Even if your variables can only be floats, you can use tuples of floats to represent arbitrary precision, of course you will have to implement many basic operations for that representation. If $f(0)-g(0)$ is a [computable number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number) different from zero, then you will be able to find out.

Comment: When it is not known that $f(0)-g(0)$ is not necessarily zero there is no algorithm to decide it in that generality. However, if $f(0)-g(0)$ can be expressed in some more restricted language, like [real closed fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_closed_field#Decidability_and_quantifier_elimination), then you can decide that it is different from zero.

Answer (score 1):

If real numbers are *really* implemented on your computer, then this is most likely acceptable.

In other words, you should use a [computer library](https://arblib.org/) that supports [interval arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic). There are many such libraries.

In particular, if you compute $1/\sqrt{2\pi}$ as lying in an interval that does not include $0.4$, then you will have proved your statement.